# Prevent duplicates in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'am trying to prevent adding duplicates on the function `add_child` but no success yet. Could you help me how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void add_family(map<string, vector<string>> &family, 
                const string &name)
{
    if (family.find(name) == family.end())
    {
        family.insert({name, vector<string>()});
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Error: Already has family <" << name << ">" << endl;
    }
}

void add_child(map<string, vector<string>> &family, const string 
               &family_name, const string &child_name)
{
    auto it = family.find(family_name);

    if (it != family.cend())
    {

        it->second.push_back(child_name);
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Error: No family <" << family_name << 
                "> for child <" << child_name << ">" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    map<string, vector<string>> family;
    add_family(family, "Family1");
    add_family(family, "Family2");
    add_family(family, "Family1"); // Error

    add_child(family, "Family1", "Name1");
    add_child(family, "Family1", "Name2");
    add_child(family, "Family1", "Name3");
    add_child(family, "Family1", "Name3"); //will create duplicate
    add_child(family, "Family2", "Name1");
    add_child(family, "Family2", "Name2");
    add_child(family, "Family2", "Name3");
    add_child(family, "Family3", "Name1"); // Error

    for (const auto &f : family)
        for (const auto &name : f.second)
            cout << f.first << " " << name << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the program is;

```
Error: Already has family <Family1>
Error: No family <Family3> for child <Name1>
Family1 Name1
Family1 Name2
Family1 Name3
Family1 Name3
Family2 Name1
Family2 Name2
Family2 Name3
```

Comment: Do you want a `set` rather than a `vector`, or do you want to produce an error? If the latter, use `std::find` on the children.

Comment: You check duplicate for family, but not for child.

Comment: Indeed, use a set instead.

Comment: What may be confusing you is that `std::vector` doesn't have a `find`. You'll have to use [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead.

Comment: You should avoid testing for key presence when adding, as non-const operator[] will create key-value (that includes the empty vector in your case) pair for you : vector<string>& family_names = family[name];

Comment: You don't check the vector to see if `child_name` already exists. You only check the map, but not the vector.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I tried to add `std::find` function like this;

`auto ret = find(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), child_name);`

But I get Segmentation fault: 11 error.

Comment: Did you first check `if(it != `family.cend())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you only check for duplicate `family_name`, not `child_name`. You can use `std::find` to search a `std::vector`

```
void add_child(map<string, vector<string>> &family, const string & family_name, const string & child_name)
{
    auto f_it = family.find(family_name);

    if (f_it != family.cend())
    {
        auto c_it = find(f_it->second.begin(), f_it->second.end(), child_name);
        if (c_it == f_it->second.end())
        {
            f_it->second.insert(c_it, child_name);
        }
        else
        {
            cerr << "Error: Already has child <" << child_name << ">" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Error: No family <" << family_name << 
                "> for child <" << child_name << ">" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Or alternatively you can use `std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>` to ensure uniqueness. Additionally, you can utilise the return value of `insert` to only lookup each name once.

```
void add_family(map<string, set<string>> &family, const string &name)
{
    if (!family.insert({name, {}}).second)
    {
        cerr << "Error: Already has family <" << name << ">" << endl;
    }
}

void add_child(map<string, set<string>> &family, const string & family_name, const string & child_name)
{
    auto it = family.find(family_name);

    if (it == family.cend())
    {
        cerr << "Error: No family <" << family_name << 
                "> for child <" << child_name << ">" << std::endl;
    } else if (!it->second.insert(child_name).second)
    {
        cerr << "Error: Already has child <" << child_name << ">" << endl;
    }
}
```

But I think this design is inelegant. I wouldn't bother with `add_family` at all. Just utilise `map` and `set`'s invariants.

```
void add_child(map<string, set<string>> &family, const string & family_name, const string & child_name)
{
    family[family_name].insert(child_name);
}
```